# Datagrid horizontal scroll automatically scrolls when row is changed by arrow key down

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I have datagird in wpf.

my problem is : Horizontal scrollbar of datagrid is automatically moved when the row is changed through arrowkey down.

In that i have observed that if i select any record in 2nd column or further columns then only horizontal scroll is automatically moved.

I have used:

```
var scp = FindVisualChild<ScrollContentPresenter>(this.dataGridResults);
            scp.RequestBringIntoView += new RequestBringIntoViewEventHandler(scp_RequestBringIntoView);
```

and:

```
void scp_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
        {
                          e.Handled = true  ;
        }
```

But this code is having no effect (debugger comes on this code, but eventually scrollbar moves...no effect)

Plz help me.

Comment: Have a look on the attached property  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility if it can help.

Comment: i attached, but not helped

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this as well, have you found one?